# My struct is initialized to nil from JSON but later need to add value

Tags: swift, struct, initialization

I am using the following structure to read from JSON.

```swift
struct ConsumedRecipe: Codable {

    var name: String
    var userStats: Stats?
    var globalStats: Stats?

    struct Stats: Codable {
        var rating: Double?
        var time: TimeInterval?
    }


    init(name: String, userStats: Stats, globalStats: Stats) {
        self.name = name
        self.userStats = userStats
        self.globalStats = globalStats
    }

}
```

Assume globalStats have values read in but the userStats does not.  So they are nil.

In app execution I get a value for userStats.rating.  If I try to assign the rating directly it remains nil.

For example:

```
userStats.rating = 2.0 remains nil.
```

I have assumed this has something to do with the whole Stats sub-struct(I am not sure what is the proper term is) being nil.  So I have tried adding the following intermediate step.

```
 var tempStats: Stats! = Stats()
        tempStats.rating = 2.0

      userStats? = tempStats
```

This still leaves the value of userStats.rating as nil.

What am I missing here?  Am I correct it is some initialization issue?

Additional Info:

I think my problem might have something to do with the init code being init from JSON:  The following:

```
  init?(json: Data) // take some JSON and try to init a ConsumedRecipe from it
    {
       do {
        let newValue =  try JSONDecoder().decode(ConsumedRecipe.self, from: json)
        self = newValue
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Reading Recipe Failed: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Those that mean I cannot that one part (userStats) later?

Comment: What do you mean by "In app execution I get a value for userStats.rating. If I try to assign the rating directly it remains nil." How do you know it is nil? Are you reading the same `userStats`? (Remember, if you assign it to anything else, or pass it to any function, you're making a copy, because you've used a struct here.)

Answer (score 0):

By app execution I mean that the user is using a rating control to give a value.  I am seeing it is null by breaking execution and checking.

I have solved the problem in a rather non elegant way.  But believe I understand the cause.  I am allowing Swift to read in the JSON file as above "init?(json: Data)".  This works well as there are actually several details to the JSON file not included in the above example.  This saves writing the full JSON logic -- specifically handling nulls.  However, nulls can crash the read.  Therefore, the user rating (which would be null) is not in the JSON file.  Hence the Stats struct is not initialized in the read.  Nor can it apparently be initialized later when needed.  (After user gives the rating feedback.)

My solution was to add a non optional property "code" in struct as shown below:

```
  struct Stats: Codable {
        var code: String
        var rating: Double?
        var time: TimeInterval?
    }
```

Then in JSON I add:

```
   "userStats": {
        "code":  "user"
    },
```

I do not presently use the property code, but my struct for userStats is initialized with rating as nil.  I can then later add a value for rating when needed.